# error in outlook in windows 10 using local server (mail server) and work in version windows7

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2

error in outlook in windows 10 using local server (mail server) and work in version outlook work in windows7 and using kassper policy

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAmEu.jpg

Comment: whats is your mail server, not sure what kassper policy your talking about either, please also test sending mail with telnet on your local machine

Comment: @MichaelEvanchik this mail server https://www.mailenable.com/  , kassper policy in the same network outlook in windows 7 work

Answer (score 0):

What's your account type? POP or IMAP? As it works on Win 7, you can compare account settings between two clients. Make sure server settings and port is correct.

What’s more, you can click More Settings > Outgoing server tab. Select “use same settings as my incoming server”.

Comment: use pop , same problem ,  this email work in mail app in windows 10

Comment: if it works in windows mail app, with the EXACT same settings.  Your software is to blame or firewall on that application